# AngularJS: assign $http.get data to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

I try to assign data from $http.get to variable in my controller.

```
 $http.get(URL).success(function (data) {
      $scope.results = data;
      console.log('results in $http.get :'+ $scope.results);
    });

 console.log('results after http.get'+ $scope.results);
```

First console log print data from get. After $http.get(url).success $scope.results prints as undefined.

Comment: As the other answers have pointed out the method is asynchronous so it returns immediately. The success callback is called when it does finish and populates your variable, and if you have set your bindings up correctly your UI will update. It's behaving exactly as it should.

Comment: Now i try to get data like this :

 var getSomething = function(){
    return $http({method:"GET", url:URL}).then(function(result){
      return result.data;
    });
  }; and assign result to variable : $scope.results = getSomething();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `$http.get` is asynchronous. So your code is not put on hold until ajax request is complete, instead it will execute the rest of the code. So your second `console.log` will be executed before the ajax request completes. At this point there is no scope variable called `$scope.results`, which is defined only after the request completes, that's why it prints `undefined`. Your first `console.log` will print only after `$http` ajax completes with success, at this point you have `$scope.results` which is assigned to `data` coming from backend.

Comment: @ktoress so how does one get http.get to not be asynchronous and get the value in scope?

Comment: The value will go to $scope anyway, but can take longer (let's say half a second). The point is when or where do you want to use it. If you want to show it on the view, you might use an event to assure it's loaded or just wait. If you need it for another function, you could call that function inside the sucess() call.

Answer (score 2):

`$http` is an `asynchronous` function. It returns instantly however it returns a `promise` not a real result. When the request is completed `onsuccess` is called.

The second (the one outside the call) `console.log` executes before `$http` returns.